# Chat message only working for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have a message box. When I click on submit it only works for the first time. Are the `onclick` events removed?

The code is like this :-

```
$("#message-box #send-message-btn").click(function(){
    var messageText=$("#message-box #textarea").val();
    $.get("getUserName",function(username,status){
        $.get("getUserByUserName?username="+username,function(user,status){
            var sentFrom=user.userId;
            var today=new Date();
            var today=getDateInFormat(today);
            today=today+"Z";
            var time=today;

            var ajaxData= {
                messageTypeId,
                messageText,
                messageReference : referenceId,
                context,
                sentFrom,
                time
            }

            $.ajax({
                url:"/addMessages",
                data: JSON.stringify(ajaxData),
                type: "POST",
                headers: { 
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log("inside sucess of add messages");
                    
                     $.get("/getMessagesByTypeContextReference?referenceId="+referenceId+"&&context="+context+"&&messageTypeId="+messageTypeId,function(messages,status){
                        var gets=[];

                        $.each(messages,function(i,message){
                            message.timestamp=getDateInFormat(new Date(message.time).addHours(-8));
                            gets.push($.get("getUserByUserId?userId="+message.sentFrom,function(user,status){
                                message.sentFromName=user.firstName+' '+user.lastName;
                            }));
                        })

                        $.when.apply($,gets).then(function(){

                            rowData.messages=messages;

                            $("#message-box").html('');
                            callHandlebars("#message-box","message-form-template",[],rowData);
                        })
                        

                    })

                },
                error : function (exception) {
                    console.log("exception :"+exception);
                }
            });
        })
    })
})
```

After submitting the message in my database I am reloading the message box html. Is that removing the event handler? What is the solution?

Comment: You are using some nested GET looks wrong.

Comment: So what should I do . I have to reload the chat application from the database. But why is the event handler getting removed ?

Comment: You could use `bind()` instead of `click()`

Comment: if i use bind instead of click the it is not working

Comment: Sorry @AtheistP3ace I forget `bind()` was replaced by `on()`. I wanted to say the same as you, my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attach the click with this selector `$("#message-box #send-message-btn")` but in your success callback it looks like you reload everything in `message-box` so the button `send-message-btn` would be replaced and any attached events lost. You can use event delegation to keep those events attached or simply reattach them after replacing the HTML of `message-box`.

To leave them attached with delegation try replacing:

```
$("#message-box #send-message-btn").click(function(){
```

with:

```
$("#message-box").on('click', '#send-message-btn', function () {
```

This attaches the event to `message-box` and because of event bubbling allows `message-box` to pass the event back to `send-message-btn` even after he has been replaced in the DOM.

Comment: Good! Happy to help! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are reloading the whole div on success. This makes you lose the click event, so it will not trigger again.

You can fix it by:

1. Re-adding the event after the div is reloaded (tested, but not really beautiful code)
2. Use on http://api.jquery.com/on/ instead of click (not tested, last time I used something like this was called "live", but it seems now is deprecated)